# Regarding .owner field of struct file_operations

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Referring to LDD-3 pg-50. It is written that

```
  struct module *owner
```

The first file_operations field is not an operation at all; it is a pointer to the module that “owns” the structure. This field is used to prevent the module from being unloaded while its operations are in use. Almost all the time, it is simply initialized to THIS_MODULE.

If we refer LDD-2 the explanation is

"This field isn’t a method like everything else in the file_operations structure. Instead, it is a pointer to the module that “owns” this structure; it is used by the kernel to maintain the module’s usage count."

Now my question is how this field is actually preventing the module from being unloaded ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

When a file which uses these operations is opened, before `.open()` file's operation is called, a function `try_module_get()` is called for the `.owner` module. This increments the module's usage counter, so the module cannot be unloaded with `rmmod` command.

When last reference to the file is dropped, and its `.release()` operation is completed, a function `module_put` is called for `.owner` module. This decrements module's usage counter, so the module can be unloaded again (unless its reference counter has been incremented for other reason).

Comment: So this is a race-free way to increment usage counter (unlike manually calling `try_module_get`, `module_put`)?

Comment: @St.Antario: Yes, it could be said so. The same effect could **not** be achieved by "normal" means: whatever reference counter or other synchronization mechanism would be used in `.open` function, nothing prevents the module to be unloaded after this function is called but before it performs synchronization.